# Is 1 hour 30 minutes enough time to catch a connection flight in Muscat, Oman?

Tags: short-connections, oman-air, mct

I am flying from London to India with a layover of 1 hour 30 minutes at Muscat Airport. My flight from London to Muscat, as well as the connecting flight from Muscat to Bangalore, is Oman Air.

Is 1:30 hours enough for me to catch my connecting flight from Muscat to Bangalore?

Do I need to re-check in my luggage?

Am I taking a risk or is this time is enough to catch my connection flight?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your flight into Muscat is on schedule, you should be okay. The airport recommends that you allow a minimum of 60 minutes. As both your flights are with Oman Air, they should sort another transfer for you if your plane is delayed.

http://www.layoverguide.com/2014/02/layover-in-muscat-oman.html

If you request it at the check on desk in London, they should just transfer your luggage to the final destination when you change planes. This can vary by airline though.